# What's the de facto standard for running a node.js server in production?

Tags: linux, node.js

How should I daemon-ize and "watchdog" it, auto-start on reboot, redirect console output to a log file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Used [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) as a daemon tool in past projects. It'll automatically restart your node.js scripts if they crash. Also, it can start and manage multiple node processes and maintain a log file for each of them individually. However it doesn't start the scripts on reboot.

Read a couple of times that people were using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to make the initial launch of forever, but i've never used it myself, never had the need to start on boot.

Answer (score 2):

This is the one of the job of `initd` or `upstart`. May be you can use `inetd` too if it is ok to start it on demand.